# Error when importing modules from different folders in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following:

```
my_project/
    hybrik/
        __init__.py
        models/
            __init__.py
            builder.py
    scripts/
        demo.py
```

And in demo.py:

```py
from hybrik.models import builder
```

When I tried to run demo.py, an error occured:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hybrik'
```

I've already had `__init__.py`, why can't it find the module?

Comment: Because "my_project" is not on your Python path.  You could add it, based on the location of `demo.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python will look for modules in locations on the `PYTHONPATH`.

Assuming the actual code in those 4 Python files makes sense, you can do the following:

- on PowerShell:

```
$env:pythonpath += ";/path/to/my_project"
```

- on Windows command prompt:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;/path/to/my_project
```

- on a Linux shell:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/my_project
```

Alternatively, you can build a package and install it in the environment of your script.